# Cannot see upstream branches in git log or gitk

Tags: git, github

I forked a GitHub repo, cloned my fork locally and add the remote "upstream" to point to the original repo. It appears everything is set up correctly, but "git log" and gitk only show branches from origin (my fork) and not upstream.

I have another machine on which everything works fine. The setup appears the same on both machines. What am I missing?

My steps:

```
git clone https://github.com:johnpankowicz/govmeeting.git
cd govmeeting
git remote add upstream https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting.git
git branch --set-upstream master upstream/master
git fetch upstream
```

If I run "git log --oneline --decorate=short", I only see the origin branches. For example:

```
dd98b4a (origin/master, master) Minor fixes in register. Documentation and minor UI changes. (#35)
```

But on my other machine, where it works, I also see the upstream branches:

```
dd98b4a (upstream/master, origin/master, master) Minor fixes in register. Documentation and minor UI changes. (#35)
```

Everything appears to be set up the same on both machines. The output is identical for each of the following commands:

$ git remote -v

```
origin  https://github.com/johnpankowicz/govmeeting.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/johnpankowicz/govmeeting.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting.git (push)
```

$ git remote show upstream

```
* remote upstream
Fetch URL: https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting.git
Push  URL: https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting.git
HEAD branch: master
Remote branch:
  master tracked
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

$ git branch -r

```
origin/fix-webapp-startup
origin/master
origin/pass-ang-arg
origin/video
upstream/master
```

$ git ls-remote upstream

```
867818be9d597ced7be5e8c1f40e033cb7f65b01        HEAD
867818be9d597ced7be5e8c1f40e033cb7f65b01        refs/heads/master
f4521d466eb98903abba4ccd92b81c2511462a1d        refs/pull/15/head
6471492dfe3e253725e66265a30d8ef895d65630        refs/pull/22/head
... etc. ...
```

Comment: Could it be that upstream/master has been committed to so that dd98b4a is no longer the head? What does `git log upstream/master` show?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It shows a different commit when I run it on the new machine. But it still shows dd9864a when I run it on the old machine. But if I run "git fetch upstream master" on the old machine, they now match, showing the later commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If upstream/master has been committed to, the relevant commit is no longer its HEAD, and won't be mentioned by git log. The other machine hasn't received the new commit yet.

Edit (More explanation): The `--decorate` looks through all the *refs* (all tags and tips of branches, both locally and on remotes) to see if any of them point to the commit. So when a new commit appears, the commit is no longer the tip of the branch, and will no longer be mentioned by `--decorate`. But `--decorate` does not actually query the remote repo for its refs, it only checks its local copy of it (all git repos contain complete local copies of its remotes). This local copy must be manually updated using e.g. `git fetch`. So on the other computer, the local copy of `upstream` was out of date.

Comment: I understand now, from you & Code-Apprentice say, why there was a difference in "git log" between the machines. But is there any way to get "git log" or another git command to show that upstream/master points to the new commit? The commit is present in the local object database since I did the fetch. It seems that it should be able to tell me that information.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer since you figured out what the problem was. But Code-Apprentice's explanation was clearer to me.

Comment: About your question, there is some command that can do this, so you can pipe `git log` to it and it will add this information, but I can't remember which command...

Comment: I found the command that I was looking for: "git log --all --oneline --decorate=short". With the "--all" option I always see what upstream/master is pointing to (assuming I did a fetch). Without that option, I only see it, if it happens to point to the HEAD of one of my local branches.

Answer (score 2):

`upstream/master` on either of your machines is actually a local copy **at the time of the most recent fetch** of the `master` branch from the `upstream` remote. It is **not** the actual branch on the remote. It will only be updated whenever you run `git fetch upstream master`. This means that if anyone commits to `master` in the original GitHub repo, then the "other" machine will not reflect those changes but your most recent clone will.